# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Scoreboard objective for ghast fireballs deflected?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Do I need to set up a system to track the fireballs a player deflects or does the statistics system already have a pre-made scoreboard objective for it? I couldn't find any page of all of the stats on the wiki so I only had what was on the `/scoreboard` command page. Is that all of them or are there others listed somewhere else?

Comment: Since you're not even damaging the fireball, I think there is indeed no scoreboard for that. I'm pretty sure you have to actually track it. I guess it would be enough to track when a fireball comes into range and then changes direction. But since the direction is stored as a vector, not an angle, that would be veeery difficult. I guess you can detect a sign flip for at least one of the three coordinates, but then a tiny redirection wouldn't be tracked.

Comment: @FabianRöling Can you store the individual vector components to the scoreboard, then compare those values against the vector the next tick?  IIRC, fireball motion isn't affected by gravity.

Comment: @MBraedley I'll try comparing the vectors. Is there a separate page for all of the statistics or is the `scoreboard` command wiki the only place to find them?

Comment: No, they should all be on the scoreboard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you can't necessarily detect fireballs *deflected*, but you can detect fireballs deflected into ghasts. The vanilla datapack has the 'Return to Sender' JSON advancement file as:

```
{
  "parent": "minecraft:nether/root",
  "display": {
    "icon": {
      "item": "minecraft:fire_charge"
    },
    "title": {
      "translate": "advancements.nether.return_to_sender.title"
    },
    "description": {
      "translate": "advancements.nether.return_to_sender.description"
    },
    "frame": "challenge",
    "show_toast": true,
    "announce_to_chat": true,
    "hidden": false
  },
  "rewards": {
    "experience": 50
  },
  "criteria": {
    "killed_ghast": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:player_killed_entity",
      "conditions": {
        "entity": {
          "type": "minecraft:ghast"
        },
        "killing_blow": {
          "is_projectile": true,
          "direct_entity": {
            "type": "minecraft:fireball"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "requirements": [
    [
      "killed_ghast"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So you could use a hidden advancement which detects that, and so every time a player gets it, add one to a dummy scoreboard and revoke the advancement.

Another *possible* thing (which I haven't tested) is the possibility of using the [player hurt entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements/List_of_triggers#minecraft:player_hurt_entity) trigger for the advancement on the ghast fireball, so then if the player "hurts" (punches) the fireball the advancement is granted, and you use the same scoreboard process as above.

I will edit whether that is possible and if it is, what JSON advancement file I used when I get around to it.